# How do i toggle between classes within 2 divs in ionic/angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

example.. i have a match between team-A and team-B. when i click on team-A, i want to add a class call 'selected' to team-A, and then if i click on team-B i want to remove the 'selected' class from team-A and add it to team-B, if i click on team-B again then i want to remove the class all together. Here is what i have so far in play.ionic. 
http://play.ionic.io/app/914bb06d2570
similarly i want it to work for match 2 and 3 as well. very appreciate the help.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="matchCtrl">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Matches</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <div ng-repeat="match in schedule" ng-init="{'awayActive': false, 'homeActive': false}">
          <div>Match {{match.matchNum}}</div>
          <div class="match">
            <div class="inline" ng-class="{'selected': awayActive}" ng-click="awayActive = !awayActive">{{match.away}}</div>
            vs
            <div class="inline" ng-class="{'selected': homeActive}" ng-click="homeActive = !homeActive">{{match.home}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

js

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic'])

.controller('matchCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.schedule = [{
      matchNum: 1,
      away: 'Team A',
      home: 'Team B'
    },{
      matchNum: 2,
      away: 'Team C',
      home: 'Team D'
    },{
      matchNum: 3,
      away: 'Team E',
      home: 'Team F'
    }];

});
```

css

```
.selected {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you or are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a common variable assigned to each `schedule` array object you can set defaults if desired, but even if you just default to nothing it will allow an easy switch between home and away selections, like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="match in schedule" ng-init="{'awayActive': false, 'homeActive': false}" ng-init="match.selection = ''">
      <div>Match {{match.matchNum}}</div>
      <div class="match">
        <div class="inline" ng-class="{'selected': match.selection  == 'away'}" ng-click="match.selection = 'away';">{{match.away}}</div>
        vs
        <div class="inline" ng-class="{'selected': match.selection  == 'home'}" ng-click="match.selection = 'home';">{{match.home}}</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/7a63c124586b